# Integrating a product of complicated exponential function and error function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions

I have a problem with the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{{\rm e}^{-t-(x^2-a^2)/t}}{t}Erf\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\,{\rm d}t, $$

where $0\le a<x$ and Erf stands for the error function. I 
tried to solve that integral using the partial integration; also I found the derivation of such
expression with respect to $a$ and then I try to integrate the new
expression... but I only get a more complicated version.

Also, I found a document with various integrals of the Error function

http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf

and the similar formula is on page 9 (Equation 32), but it is not
the same...

Please if you have some suggestions how to solve such integral?

Comment: Well, I hope because there is a closed form expression for a very
similar integral :) Also, I got that such integral is equal to
$$=a\int_0^1\frac{e^{-2\sqrt{x^2-a^2+a^2t^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2+a^2
t^2}}\,{\rm d}t$$ but I can't solve that integral also...

Comment: I suggest you show some of your steps and this form of the integral in the body of your question. This way yoy are more likely to get help